# Where am I iterating over my ResultSet one time too many? or why is it closed?

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework, playframework-2.1, anorm

I am using anorm to access data on my DB. The DB is written to using another service, which is made in Java, and persist using ebean.

I have the following scala object

```
import java.sql.Connection

import scala.concurrent.{ Future, blocking, future }
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import anorm.{ SQL, SqlQuery, SqlRow, sqlToSimple, toParameterValue }
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.DB

object Queries {

  private val readDataSource: String = play.Configuration.root().getString("data.provider.api.source", "default")
  //better IO execution context

  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

  private val dataSetDescription: SqlQuery = SQL("SELECT DISTINCT platform, name FROM data_nugget")

  private val identityCreationTime: SqlQuery = SQL("SELECT i.creation_time FROM identity i WHERE platform = {pfm} AND userid = {uid};")

  private val identityData: SqlQuery = SQL("SELECT n.name, n.value FROM data_nugget n WHERE platform = {pfm} AND userid = {uid};")

  private val playerData: SqlQuery = SQL("SELECT n.platform, n.name, n.value, r.userid, r.registration_time FROM data_nugget n JOIN registration r ON n.platform=r.platform AND n.userid=r.userid  WHERE r.playerid = {pid} AND r.application = {app};")

  private def withAsyncAnormConnection(function: Connection => Stream[SqlRow]): Future[List[SqlRow]] = {
    future {
      blocking {
        DB.withConnection(readDataSource)(c => function(c)).toList
      }
    }
  }

  def fetchDistinctDataNames(): Future[List[SqlRow]] = {
    withAsyncAnormConnection(implicit c => dataSetDescription())
  }

  def fetchIdentityCreationTime(platform: String, userid: String): Future[List[SqlRow]] = {
    withAsyncAnormConnection(implicit c => identityCreationTime.on("pfm" -> platform, "uid" -> userid)())
  }

  def fetchIdentityData(platform: String, userid: String): Future[List[SqlRow]] = {
    withAsyncAnormConnection(implicit c => identityData.on("pfm" -> platform, "uid" -> userid)())
  }

  def fetchRegistrationData(game: String, playerid: String): Future[List[SqlRow]] = {
    withAsyncAnormConnection(implicit c => playerData.on("app" -> game, "pid" -> playerid)())
  }

}
```

I use it to wrap my SQL queries executions within futures.

Everytime I run any of those queries I obtain an error with this following stack trace :

```
(Error,com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:794)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7139)
anorm.Sql$$anonfun$resultSetToStream$1.apply(Anorm.scala:527)
anorm.Sql$$anonfun$resultSetToStream$1.apply(Anorm.scala:527)
anorm.Useful$.unfold(Anorm.scala:315)
anorm.Useful$$anonfun$unfold$1.apply(Anorm.scala:317)
anorm.Useful$$anonfun$unfold$1.apply(Anorm.scala:317)
scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1078)
scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1070)
scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:548)
scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:178)
scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.to(TraversableLike.scala:629)
scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.to(Traversable.scala:105)
scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:243)
scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toList(Traversable.scala:105)
controllers.dataprovider.data.Queries$$anonfun$withAsyncAnormConnection$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Queries.scala:31)
controllers.dataprovider.data.Queries$$anonfun$withAsyncAnormConnection$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Queries.scala:31)
scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$DefaultThreadFactory$$anon$2$$anon$3.block(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:44)
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:2803)
scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$DefaultThreadFactory$$anon$2.blockOn(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:41)
scala.concurrent.package$.blocking(package.scala:50)
controllers.dataprovider.data.Queries$$anonfun$withAsyncAnormConnection$1.apply(Queries.scala:30)
controllers.dataprovider.data.Queries$$anonfun$withAsyncAnormConnection$1.apply(Queries.scala:30)
scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1417)
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104))
```

I already encountered those on previous Java services using jdbc but here I am not touching  the ResultSet, and I am even returning a list asap from the Stream of rows I receive from the connection.

**What is happening? Where am I closing the ResultSet? What did I refactor wrong?**

As a note, on the prototype of this service (when everything was in the controller) I used to have the SQL("...") directly in the code with something like that:

```
future {
    blocking {
      DB.withConnection(implicit c => {
        SQL("SELECT DISTINCT platform, name FROM data_nugget")().map(row => (row[String]("platform"), row[String]("name"))).toArray
      })
    }
  }
```

and it worked just fine.

PS : Sorry for the long copy/paste of stacktrace and the code ... trying to be detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it myself and it is a very fine line.

I changed this function

```
  private def withAsyncAnormConnection(function: Connection => Stream[SqlRow]): Future[List[SqlRow]] = {
    future {
      blocking {
        DB.withConnection(readDataSource)(c => function(c)).toList
      }
    }
  }
```

to THIS:

```
  private def withAsyncAnormConnection(function: Connection => Stream[SqlRow]): Future[List[SqlRow]] = {
    future {
      blocking {
        DB.withConnection(readDataSource)(c => function(c).toList)
      }
    }
  }
```

The trick is that I am using the "loan-pattern" of `withConnection`, so I need to iter through the `Stream` to get all the rows before I release  the connection.
The connection is alive only within this round brackets `(c => function(c).toList)`

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between the code that is working for you and the code that is not working.  In your working example, you are calling `map` on the lazy `Stream` of `Row` instances.  In the non-working example, you are calling `toList` without using `map`.  Maybe `map` is forcing the full processing of the underlying `ResultSet` within the `withConnection` block and `toList` is not, leaving it lazy until you get outside of the `withConnection` block after which the underlying `ResultSet` is closed.  Maybe you can modify your new code to try and map the results (mapping the `Row` to itself, no actual mapping logic) and see if this fixes anything.

Comment: I tried what you suggested with a println for debug purpose: `map(row => { println(row.mkString(", "); row}).toList`  All I get is the first element of the `ResultSet` or `Stream` and then the stacktrace I had in my question. I feel the `Stream` might be the issue, but calling the `force` function on it gave me the error again.

Comment: thanks to your suggestion I ended finding the bug. It was more or less related.